# Do the sites using password maximum limit store the passwords in plain text?

Tags: security

I have seen some sites imposing maximum password length. Do those sites store passwords in plain text? What could be any other reasons?

Comment: Because of [chimpanzees](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33471/235964). See also:  https://security.stackexchange.com/a/243095/235964

Comment: @nobody: that is the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Nowdays the good practice is to store users' passwords in hashes. So when you set a new password for your account, it's stored as a hash of the password. It means any time when server needs to check the password it checks hashes to be the same.
The reason why passwords have length limit is because hashing process takes a lot of time and a lot of power.
The other reason is a user that suggests too long password so it causes a server-side error :)

Comment: "The reason why passwords have length limit is because hashing process takes a lot of time and a lot of power." - no, that is most certainly not the reason. Hashing 6 chars and 600 chars with bcrypt takes the same (artificially long) time.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well, bcrypt has max input limit of 72 bytes, so you can't hash a 600 char password directly with it.

Comment: @nobody: TIL. Thanks! Still I maintain my position: even in the case of expensive/slow function like bcrypt, energy/time cost is insignificant for all legitimate uses.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yeah, you're totally right about that, I was just nitpicking :)